# How to open a downloaded file

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am writing an application for Xamarin.iOS, but an answer in native iOS would suffice. After I download a file (image or pdf) I want to open it:

```
public void DidFinishDownloading(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, NSUrl location)
{
    // how to open location?
}
```

I tried `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(location);` but nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, could you share the code of downloading or where you stored path in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you mind using **[WKWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview)** to load the local file, and if you store the file in `Library/Caches/` of [Application directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories), you could use follow ways to load the downloaded file.

Get the `cache` path:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
cache = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "Library", "Caches");
Console.WriteLine("path is : "+cache);
```

Load a `tree.png` in **WKWebView**:

```
 webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
 View.AddSubview(webView);

 NSUrl nSUrl = new NSUrl("file://" + cache + "/tree.png");
 webView.LoadFileUrl(nSUrl, nSUrl);
```

Here is the output:

```
2020-10-28 10:27:47.303745+0800 IOSSplashScreen[4370:73093] path is : /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C30029F0-379A-4255-B38B-27E2BAAC8CC1/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C7D7CA5-7394-414A-897F-8F1A278838A8/Documents/../Library/Caches
```

And effect:

[image]